# Trying to use Javascript to change img src in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use Javascript to change the src attribute of an image (id: big-img) to that of a smaller image (class: clicky) when the smaller image is clicked to create . Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. Code provided below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!-- Always use meta tags in head first -->
    <!-- Sets character encoding (utf-8 = unicode) -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Sets width of the page to width of the device and sets initial zoom
    value to 1.0. Used for mobile viewing -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Linking in bootstrap (css) and author styles. -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- For simple Javascript concept exercises -->
    <div id="practice">
      <p>
        Does this work?
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- For image related complex(ish) Javascript exercises -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="clicky col-md-3"><img src="img/img1.jpg"></div>
          <div class="clicky col-md-3"><img src="img/img2.jpg"></div>
          <div class="clicky col-md-3"><img src="img/img3.jpg"></div>
          <div class="clicky col-md-3"><img src="img/img4.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <img id="big-img"
           class="large-img"
           src="img/img1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="col-md-12">
                <img id="bigImage"
                  class="large-img"
                  src="img_1.jpg"
                  alt="graffittied building"/>
            </div> -->


    <!-- Linking in Jquery library, bootstrap (JS) and my scripts. Imported in
    that order due to bootstrap requiring some Jquery features so needs to be
    lower in source order -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".clicky").click(function(){
  $("#big-img").attr('src',
    $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `clicky` is not `img` element it doesn't have `src` attribute thus the code is working as expected.

You need to traverse to `img` element the fetch its attribute, there are various ways to achieve that. Here in code I have used `.find()` method since `img` is child of `clicky` element

```
$(".clicky").click(function(){
    $("#big-img").attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

OR, You can bind event with `img` element then your code will work

```
$(".clicky img").click(function(){
    $("#big-img").attr('src', this.src);
    //$("#big-img").attr('src',  $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function change_img(){
    $(document).on("click",".clicky img",function(){
        var el = $(this);
        var src = $.trim(el.attr("src"));
        (src !=="") ? $("#big-img").attr("src",src) : '';
    });
}

$(function(){
    change_img(); 
});
```

Comment: are you referring to?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".clicky").click(function(){
  $("#big-img").attr('src',
    $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refers to the clicked element : `<div>`. You need to get `img` thats inside the div.

```
$(".clicky").click(function(){
  $("#big-img").attr('src',$('img', this).attr('src'));
});
```

To complete :

```
$(".clicky").on('click', function(e){
  $("#big-img").attr('src',$('img', this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Why `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: To prevent the page scroll up on click, now that you ask its not needed here as its a div that is clicked

Answer (score 0):

clicky class is attached to a div not to an img so it does not have a src attribute

What you can do is this:

```
$(".clicky > img").click(function(){
  $("#big-img").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

But if you want to to attach the listener on the div, you can do this:

```
$(".clicky").click(function(){
  $("#big-img").attr('src', $(this).find("img").attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: OP may want his listener over `div` not on `img`

Comment: I've updated my answer Rayon, just in case the OP really want that